# aggregate date and calculate mean

Tags: r, date, aggregate

I have this a dataframe with a long list of dates in one column and values in another column, that looks like this:

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(date= as.Date(c('2010-09-05', '2011-09-06', '2010-09-13', 
                                 '2011-09-14', '2010-09-23', '2011-09-24',
                                 '2010-10-05', '2011-10-06', '2010-10-13', 
                                 '2011-10-14', '2010-10-23', '2011-10-24')),
                 value= rnorm(12))
```

I need to calculate the mean value in each 10 day period of each month, but irrespective of year, like this:

```
dfNeeded <- data.frame(datePeriod=c('period.Sept0.10', 'period.Sept11.20', 'period.Sept21.30',
                                    'period.Oct0.10', 'period.Oct11.20', 'period.Oct21.31'),
                       meanValue=c(mean(df$value[c(1,2)]), 
                                   mean(df$value[c(3,4)]),
                                   mean(df$value[c(5,6)]),
                                   mean(df$value[c(7,8)]), 
                                   mean(df$value[c(9,10)]),
                                   mean(df$value[c(11,12)])))
```

Is there a fast way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to do it, which uses the `lubridate` package for month and day extraction, but you can do it with base R date functions :

```
library(lubridate)
df$period <- paste(month(df$date),cut(day(df$date),breaks=c(0,10,20,31)),sep="-")
aggregate(df$value, list(period=df$period), mean)
```

Which gives :

```
      period          x
1  10-(0,10] -0.5606859
2 10-(10,20] -0.7272449
3 10-(20,31] -0.7377896
4   9-(0,10] -0.4648183
5  9-(10,20] -0.6306283
6  9-(20,31]  0.4675903
```

Comment: (+1) maybe a call to `month(.)` as: `month(df$date, label = TRUE)` will get closer to OP's "exact" answer. `cut` is such a handy function!

Comment: Brilliant, many thanks. I'm trying to limit learning of aggregation functions to `plyr` functions, so this is code I went for: `df$period <- paste(month(df$date,label=T),cut(day(df$date),breaks=c(0,10,20,31)),sep="-")
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(period), summarise, meanValue=mean(value))`

Answer (score 2):

This approach with format.Date and modulo arithmetic should be reasonably fast:

```
tapply(df$value, list( format(df$date, "%b"), as.POSIXlt(df$date)$mday %/% 10), mean)
            0         1        2
Oct -0.560686 -0.727245 -0.73779
Sep -0.464818 -0.630628  0.46759
```

I'm not sure how it would compare to the aggregate approach:

```
aggregate(df$value, list( format(df$date, "%b"), as.POSIXlt(df$date)$mday %/% 10), mean)
  Group.1 Group.2         x
1     Oct       0 -0.560686
2     Sep       0 -0.464818
3     Oct       1 -0.727245
4     Sep       1 -0.630628
5     Oct       2 -0.737790
6     Sep       2  0.467590
```